# Converting Boolean array into counter

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, counter

I have a Boolean array of size 12. At any time, only one index will be true. The array is connected to 12 position on Knob, Starting from 0 to 11. If we move the knob clockwise from position 5 to 6, the index 5 in array will become false and index 6 will be True. After 11 position knob will move back to 0.

I want to create a counter that increase or decrease as knob moves clockwise or counter clockwise. The counter will also continue to increase, if the position is change from 11 to 0. Similarly, on moving from 0 to 12, the counter will decrease.

In the very simplified way, i want Boolean Array to behave like a rotary encoder.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to showcase at least some code or ideas for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it with an array. Create an object that has this specific functionality

```
public class RotaryEncoder {
     private int totalPositions:
     public int ActiveIndex = { get; private set; }

     public RotaryEncoder(int totalPositions) {
          this.totalPositions = totalPositions;
          this.ActiveIndex = 0;
     }

     public void IncreasePosition() {
         ActiveIndex = ActiveIndex + 1 == totalPositions ? 0 : ActiveIndex + 1;
     }
}
```

You get the idea on how to decrease position. The boolean array itself has no extra properties as active index.

A different approach, would have you create a collection of new objects that held both a boolean and an index and change both the active and new active item at once.  (Surely less efficient).

If course, you would again have to encapsulate then into a class, as you don't want implementation details to leak out and let consumers handle your data structure as they please.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetCounter(new[] { false, false, false, true, false }));
        Console.WriteLine(GetCounter(new[] { false, false, false, false, true }));
        Console.WriteLine(GetCounter(new[] { true, false, false, false, false }));
        Console.WriteLine(GetCounter(new[] { false, true, false, false, false }));
    }

    public static int GetCounter(bool[] array)
    {
        if (array.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Array must at least be of size 1");

        int counter = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i])
            {
                if (counter != -1)
                    throw new Exception("Multiple positions are true in the array");
                counter = i;
            }
        }

        if (counter == -1)
            throw new Exception("No positions are true in the array");
        return counter;

    }
```

This prints the following:

```
    3
    4
    0
    1
```

(I used an array of length 5 for the example, but it works with any array length > 0)

Answer (score 0):

And here is the solution with the boolean array:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var values = new[]
        {
            false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false
        };
        var length = values.Length;
        var counter = 0;
        var previous = 0;
        var current = 0;

        while (counter < 25) // or any condition
        {
            current = counter++ % length;
            values[previous] = false;
            values[current] = true;
            previous = current;

            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {counter}\tIndex: {current}\t{string.Join(",\t", values)}");
        }
    }
```

And the produced output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
public class RotaryEncoder
{
    private const int DefaultTotalPositions = 11;
    
    private readonly int _totalPositions;

    public bool[] Knobs => GetArray();
    
    public int Position { get; private set; }
    
    public RotaryEncoder() : this(DefaultTotalPositions)
    {
        
    }
    
    public RotaryEncoder(int totalPositions)
    {
        if(totalPositions <= 0) 
        {           
            totalPositions = DefaultTotalPositions; 
        }
        
        _totalPositions = totalPositions;       
    }
    
    public void Increase() => Increase(1);
    
    public void Decrease() => Decrease(1);
    
    public void Increase(int positions)
    {
        var adjustedPosition = AdjustBeforeAddOrSubtract(Position + positions);
        Position = adjustedPosition;            
    }
    
    public void Decrease(int positions)
    {
        var adjustedPosition = AdjustBeforeAddOrSubtract(Position - positions);
        Position = adjustedPosition;                
    }
    
    
    private bool[] GetArray()
    {
        var knobs = new bool[_totalPositions];
        knobs[Position] = true;         
        return knobs;
    }

    private int AdjustBeforeAddOrSubtract(int positions)
    {
        return positions > _totalPositions || positions < 0 ? 0 : positions;
    }
}
```

example usage :

```
var knobs = new RotaryEncoder(); // will create a 11 knobs
knobs.Increase(); // would increase by 1
// knobs.Increase(6); // would increase by 6
var currentknobs = knobs.Knobs; // would return a boolean array with the current knobs
```

you can then extend the class to fit your needs.